# Docker still deletes databases on rebuild

Tags: database, docker, docker-compose

I have some project in docker. When i recreating docker app, docker still deleting old databases in localhost. I did not find any solution on internet. Is there someone who knows how this problem solved?

Thanks for the responding

There is my docker file

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
ENV DOCKER=1
ENV MASTER_URL_DOCKERFILE='http://website/'
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    libpng-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev libxpm-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --with-gd \
    --with-webp-dir \
    --with-jpeg-dir \
    --with-png-dir \
    --with-zlib-dir \
    --with-xpm-dir \
    --with-freetype-dir

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-install calendar && docker-php-ext-configure calendar
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/expires.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
COPY core /var/www/core/
COPY chainway/src /var/www/html/
COPY chainway/docker/app/ /usr/local/bin/
RUN service apache2 restart
```

And there is how i running containers

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$(dirname $0)

cd $DIR

wget –V
wget -O "$DIR/docker/db/dump.sql" "http://website/senddatabasetolocalhost.php?auth=authkey"

docker-compose stop

docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: You should map a volume to docker host, that way files won't get deleted. Please share your docker-compose or docker file here so you can get help.

Comment: Don't store the database in a container but in a volume.

Comment: I update docker file :) @arunes

Comment: Include how you are running the container, and what directory of the container has the database content.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/storage/ and https://docs.docker.com/get-started/05_persisting_data/

Comment: What is `docker-compose` doing? We need to see the docker-compose.yml. And we still need to know what directory inside your container includes the database content.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a volumes in docker-compose.yml like this :

```
volumes:
  - $PWD/my_sql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: But we are downloading databases from servers if i add volumes to docker-compose.yml there is problem with downloading databases from server. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: You are using wget for downloading the dump.sql from OS. Now change a path to download into $PWD/my_sql where $PWD is for example /home/you/my_sql. The path on your local is mounted into docker container /var/lib/mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can store your db data using volumes.

Add to your docker-compose.yml file in mysql section:

```
  mysql:
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

And to the end of the file:

```
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: But we are downloading databases from servers if i add volumes to docker-compose.yml there is problem with downloading databases from server. 
Or I'm wrong?

Comment: Do you download a database from your server as a SQL dump? Just import it to docker using command docker exec -i db_container mysql -uroot -proot db_name < dump.sql. No need to copy anything as a file!